# hacer algo al autenticar usuario en Odoo 16

Tags: odoo, autenticación

Estoy haciedo un proyecto de curso en Odoo 16 y necesito calcular la cantidad de solicitudes pendientes para mostrarlas al usuario al autenticarse este. Buscando encontré que se hace a través de redefinir la función "authenticate" pero no me está funcionando, esta es mi clase User con la función:

```
from odoo import api, fields, models

class User(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.users'
    
    @api.model
    def authenticate(self, db, login, password, user_agent_env):
        auth =  super(User, self).authenticate(db, login, password, user_agent_env)
        solicitudes = 20
        # Mandar la notificación
        print("AUTENTICADO")
        return auth
```

y estos son los errores que me saca:

File "d:\trabajo\otros\odoo-16.0\addons\website\models\res_users.py", line 73, in authenticate
uid = super(ResUsers, cls).authenticate(db, login, password, user_agent_env)
TypeError: authenticate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_agent_env'

y a veces me saca este otro:

File "d:\trabajo\otros\odoo-16.0\modules\proyecto_curso\models\user.py", line 9, in authenticate
auth =  super(User, self).authenticate(db, login, password, user_agent_env)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

acá están todas las trazas

```
2023-09-12 14:30:18,768 7084 INFO ? odoo.addons.bus.models.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
2023-09-12 14:31:11,357 7084 ERROR proyecto_curso odoo.http: Exception during request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Carlos\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 1964, in __call__
    response = request._serve_db()
  File "D:\Carlos\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 1549, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "D:\Carlos\odoo-16.0\odoo\service\model.py", line 134, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "D:\Carlos\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 1578, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "D:\Carlos\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 1691, in dispatch
    return self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "d:\carlos\odoo-16.0\addons\website\models\ir_http.py", line 227, in _dispatch
    response = super()._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "D:\Carlos\odoo-16.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 140, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "D:\Carlos\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 673, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "d:\carlos\odoo-16.0\addons\website\controllers\main.py", line 184, in web_login
    return super().web_login(*args, **kw)
  File "D:\Carlos\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 673, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "d:\carlos\odoo-16.0\addons\auth_signup\controllers\main.py", line 24, in web_login
    response = super().web_login(*args, **kw)
  File "D:\Carlos\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 673, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "d:\carlos\odoo-16.0\addons\web\controllers\home.py", line 103, in web_login
    uid = request.session.authenticate(request.db, request.params['login'], request.params['password'])
  File "D:\Carlos\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 918, in authenticate
    pre_uid = registry['res.users'].authenticate(dbname, login, password, wsgienv)
TypeError: authenticate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_agent_env'
2023-09-12 14:31:11,358 7084 INFO proyecto_curso werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2023 14:31:11] "POST /web/login HTTP/1.1" 500 - 1 0.001 0.015
```

Alguien me puede ayudar a saber como corregir esto? Gracias

Comment: Lo pudiste solucionar?

Comment: Gracias @Legna por responder, esto aun no lo he podido solucionar, le he dicho al profesor que estoy pausado en ello y he estado haciendo otras cosas de otro curso del doctorado, espero realmente que me puedas ayudar con esto, gracias

Comment: Prueba llamar al super sin argumentos. `auth = super().authenticate(db, login, password, user_agent_env)`. Pon toda la traza de error que te está dando. Hay partes importantes en zonas anteriores del mensaje de error que es necesario revisar.

Comment: Buenas @Legna, primero gracias por las molestias, probé con la forma que me dices  y tampoco funciona, actualicé la pregunta poniendo las trazas como me dijiste, espero realmente puedas ayudarme

Comment: no sé si es exactamente lo que quieres. En odoo 14 tienes los home actions que sirven para especificar que hacer con el usuario una vez que se loguea. Puedes redirigir a dicho usuario a una vista si cumple una condición y mostrarle eso que quieres. Dime si necesitas mas orientación